# Keras submodel needs to be built

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am creating a python class that inherits from a keras model.

```py
class MyModel(tf.keras.models.Model):

    def __init__(self, size, input_shape):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(size, input_shape=(input_shape,))

    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.layer(inputs)

model = MyModel(5, 30)
model.summary()
```

This gives me this error:

```
ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or calling `fit()` with some data, or specify an `input_shape` argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build.
```

It is fixed if I add one line after creating the model:

```
model = MyModel(5, 30)
model(tf.keras.layers.Input((30,)))
model.summary()
```

But it doesn't look the best way of doing this. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you even need a class for this?

Comment: As I thought was obvious, my model is much more complex and I only showed a minimal example with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `self.build()` in the constructor.

Something like this:

```py
class MyModel(tf.keras.models.Model):

    def __init__(self, size, input_shape):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(size, input_shape=(input_shape,))
        self.build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.layer(inputs)

model = MyModel(2, (5, 30))
model.summary()
```